# When to use Multithread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

When do you use threads in a application? For example, in simple CRUD operations, use of smtp, calling webservices that may take a few time if the server is facing bandwith issues, etc.

To be honest, i don't know how to determine if i need to use a thread (i know that it must be when we're excepting that a operation will take a few time to be done).

This may be a "noob" question but it'll be great if you share with me your experience in threads.

Thanks

Comment: What are you actually trying to do. It might be easier for us to tell you whether or not threads help solve your problem. Otherwise this question is looking like a candidate for "close as not a real question".

Comment: I need to study the use of multithreads for my next costumer because my team leader asked it. But first i'm trying to figure out when i should use the threads, that's why i asked this question. To see when other devs use threads in "real world applications".

Comment: I like to view multi-threading scenarios from a resource perspective. In other words, UI (graphics), networking, disk IO, CPU (cores), RAM etc. I find that helps when deciding where to use multi-threading in the general sense at least. Great question btw. noob or otherwise :-)

Comment: OK, all clear now. For me, I use threads so that my CPU bound numerical analysis program can saturate the available processors.

Comment: 4 years after asking this i'm now dealing with it in PHP. It's great to look back and see how we grow up in knowledge thanks to communities like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I added C# and .NET tags to your question because you mention C# in your title.  If that is not accurate, feel free to remove the tags.

There are different styles of multithreading.  For example, there are asynchronous operations with callback functions.  .NET 4 introduces the parallel Linq library.  The style of multithreading you would use, or whether to use any at all, depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Parallel execution, such as what parallel Linq would generally be trying to do, takes advantage of multiple processor cores executing instructions that do not need to wait for data from each other.  There are many sources for such algorithms outside Linq, such as [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~scandal/nesl/algorithms.html).  However, it is possible that parallel execution may be unable to you or that it does not suit your application.

More traditional multithreading takes advantage of threading within the .NET library (in this case) as provided by `System.Thread`.  Remember that there is some overhead in starting processes on threads, so only use threads when the advantages of doing so outweigh this overhead.  Generally speaking, you would only want to use this type of single-processor multithreading when the task running under the thread will have long gaps in which the processor could be doing something else.  For example, I/O from hard disk (and, consequently, from a database system that uses one) is many orders of magnitude slower than memory access.  Network access can also be slow, as another example.  Multithreading could allow another process to be running while waiting for these slow (compared to the processor) operations to complete.

Another example when I have used traditional multithreading is to cache some values the first time a particular ASP.NET page is accessed within a session.  I kick off a thread so that the user does not have to wait for the caching to complete before interacting with the page.  I also regulate the behavior when the caching does not complete before the user requests another page so that, if the caching does not complete, it is not a problem.  It simply makes some further requests faster that were previously too slow.

Consider also the cost that multithreading has to the maintainability of your application.  Threaded applications can be harder to debug, for example.

I hope this answers your question at least somewhat.

Comment: so parallel programming with .net encapsulates multithreading? is it correct affirm that?

Comment: @EdwinSnts I'm not entirely sure what you are asking.  Multiple threads, whether created by parallel Linq or some other way, can end up running on different processor cores.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Does it mean If I don use parallel linq, the instructions from my code will be executed in only one core? even if the computer hosting it has multicore processors?

Comment: Sorry, it might be another questions, I will post it

Answer (score 2):

Joseph Albahari summarized it very well [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Threadings_Uses_and_Misuses):

- Maintaining a responsive user interface
- Making efficient use of an otherwise blocked CPU
- Parallel programming
- Speculative execution
- Allowing requests to be processed simultaneously

Answer (score 1):

One reason to use threads is to split large, CPU-bound tasks across a number of CPUs/cores, to finish faster. Another is to let an extended task execute asynchronously, so the foreground can remain responsive while it runs.

Your examples seem to be concentrating on the second of these. While it can be a good reason, if you can use asynchronous I/O instead, that's usually preferable (e.g., almost anything using sockets can/will be better off using the socket(s) asynchronously). Asynchronous I/O is easier to cancel, and it'll usually have lower CPU overhead as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use threads when you need different execution paths. This leads(when done correctly) to more responsive and/or faster applications but also leads to more complex code and debugging.

In a simple CRUD scenario maybe is not that useful, but maybe your UI is consuming a slow web service. If you your code is tied to your UI thread you will have unresponsive UI between the service calls.

In that case, using System.Threading.Threads maybe be overkill because you don't need so much control. Using a BackgrounWorker maybe a better choice.

Threading is something difficult to master, but the benefits when used correctly are huge, performance is the most common.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow you have answered your question by yourself. Using threads whenever you execute time consuming operations is right choice. Also you should it in situations when you want to make things faster. For example you want to process some amount of files - each file can be processed by different thread.

By using threads you can better utilize power of multi-core/processor machines.

Monitoring some data in background of your application.

There are dozens of such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Realising my comment might suffice as an answer ...

I like to view multi-threading scenarios from a resource perspective. In other words, UI (graphics), networking, disk IO, CPU (cores), RAM etc. I find that helps when deciding where to use multi-threading in the general sense at least.

The reasoning behind this is simply that I can take advantage of one resource on  a specific thread (eg. Disk IO) while at the same time using another thread to accomplish something else using a different resource.