# Local Server for Gaming C#

Tags: c#

[C#] Hello all, I am curious on how I can go about creating my own local server and allowing people outside to connect an return data stored on it. I am not looking for an "XNA" solution. I would like to kind of digest the bare bones of client to server. Here is an outline for what I am looking for:

My PC
[Server] -> Constantly Updates/Receives Player data so it can be obtained by other PC's. Stores data from other clients.

[Client PC] -> Writes to server (Creates new player data/updates) and obtains further information to update visuals, other players, etc.

Comment: What's your actual question? As written, this is too broad. Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I guess the general question is basically how can I initialize this server locally so others can grab my local data stored on my PC

Comment: An example would be a Minecraft server. This game server client allows you to locally start a server by port forwarding and storing all the data on your PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't something small that anyone can just do, especially if you are just getting into programming. I would first start out small, make a few smaller applications, play around with the .NET framework libraries and get comfortable (I would specifically look at System.Net/System.Net.Sockets as well as possibly System.Security for SSL encryption). The networking component will be huge in this as you'll need to implement a system to handle the constant communication and be able to respond quickly (any lag can be seen as dropped packets from a networking standpoint and cause client time outs). You'll also want to think about what kind of data you are serving up (saved games, player data, whether it's personal information (such as passwords, email addresses, etc)) and how you are going to store that data. There are many paid and free technologies for this (Postgres, SQL, MySQL, etc). Please do a quick google on some of thee items I have mentioned and you'll see why it takes years to develop games and the back end systems to support multiplayer.

If you are the type of learner to plug things in and learn by tearing someone else's code apart, I would take a look at some of the articles below.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1415/Introduction-to-TCP-client-server-in-C

http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-multi-threaded-server-socket.htm

Here's some MSDN articles dissecting the different classes of the System.Net namespace and functions of it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate(v=vs.110).aspx

You'll also want to look at using threading to make sure the server isn't only processing one request at a time. There are many approaches to this but here is some basic examples of using threads.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/thread

[When to use Multithread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346542/when-to-use-multithread) (Some pointers how on and when to use threads on our very own S/O site :) ).

Here's the DL on threading from MSDN

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx

Not meant to discourage you but more to show you the type of effort you'll have to put in to this sort of project. What you want to do is completely doable, but will require some brain training and head scratching. Apologies if it sound condescending, just trying to coach and am unsure of your level of expertise in c#! Best of luck to you though friend, hopefully this turns into a great learning experience!

Comment: I am very familiar with .Net, I just never worked on applications like this before. Thank you for the information!

Comment: Apologies to the moderators if I'm not supposed to use that many links or whatnot, feel free to correct my etiquette but just trying to point him in some general direction as his question is rather board and encompassing. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @TylerEsposito I had to attempt one of these on a corporate level for a client/server communication role. It took me weeks to get a system somewhat stable and good. It is very frustrating and challenging at times but it is a wonderful thing to learn (there are many libraries out there and pre-written code to do this for you but this will show you the guts of networking). Best of luck!